# A dialogue in "La Femme et le TGV"

Tags: cinéma, dialogues

I watched the movie "La Femme et le TGV". During the first dialogue at the beginning (a few early minutes of the movie), the lady is bicycling and a car (driven by a young man) makes dust near her. As a reaction, the lady tells him something.

I cannot recognize what the lady tells him. Something like: "vous devrez a ?what?"

I could not find a French subtitle for the movie.

Did you watch this movie? Could you tell me what she is saying in that dialogue?

Comment: @reyedy thank you so much for you edit!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

She says « Vous devriez avoir honte ! » which means "You should be ashamed!"

This is a good example of an *avoir + [noun]* phrase. Many expressions that are *be + [adjective]* in English are rendered like this in French:

> avoir faim = to be hungry

> avoir froid = to be cold

> avoir raison = to be right

And among them is *avoir honte*, where *honte* is literally "shame".

Comment: You have right! ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: I have some other question about that movie which is not related to the language but to the subject of the film. So  i would like to have e discussion with you. Can you send me  an email?  my yahoo email   is  "alitghv".(As it is  also written in my profile). Thank you

Comment: @AliTaghavi I can, but first, are you sure it's something I'm best suited to answer? I have no particular knowledge of the movie — I just found a clip somewhere to listen to for this question. Maybe the community would have more interesting things to say about the subject matter.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.my question is not very professional from the view of cinema. It is just a question about a particular doalog I would be very grateful if you contact me via yahoo email.